# Which network protocol is used by popular io games like diep.io?

Tags: networking, websocket, io, udp, game-development

Recently, I tried to have a look at the network activity on sites like agar.io, diep.io, and zombsroyale.io.

Specifically, I had a look at Firefox and Chromium developer tools.

However, I was puzzled that there wasn't much going on with WebSockets. TCP doesn't seem to be used for game updates otherwise we would have sockets at least every 100ms. I am aware that all io games used WebSockets until recently but maybe the progress of webrtc made the switch. All the websites that I listed use wasm or Unity so it's hard to dig into the library they use for networking.

Did this website switch to UDP or WebRTC for sending game updates?
Or is there a reason that we can't see all websockets in the developer's tools?

Answer (score -1):

Popular io games like diep.io use the TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) network protocol. TCP is a reliable protocol that guarantees delivery of data in the correct order. This makes it a good choice for games that require precise synchronization between players, such as diep.io.

However, TCP is not without its drawbacks. It can be slower than other protocols, such as UDP, because it adds overhead to the data that is being sent. This overhead is used to ensure that the data is delivered reliably.

In diep.io, the use of TCP is justified by the need for precise synchronization between players. The game is a fast-paced shooter where players need to be able to react quickly to the actions of other players. If the data that is being sent between players is not reliable, it can lead to a frustrating experience for all involved.

Comment: Then why doesn't Firefox developers tool show that websockets are sent regularly ?
PS It smells like a ChatGPT answer :/